# Spoof MAC address from IP command

Tags: android, mac-address, ifconfig

I'm trying to spoof my MAC address on a modified version of Linux (Android). The main problem is that because it has been stripped down, the `ifconfig` command has been taken out, and I only can use the `ip` busybox command.

I've been trying to use:

```
ip link set address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx dev tiwlan0
```

However I get this error:

```
ip: socket: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you have chroot and mount command in the Andriod's busybox.  (If not, just add them and rebuild the busybox.)

1. Untar a full Linux filesystem into a disk (networked/nfs) in Android.
2. Mount it
3. chroot to that system

You should now have a new shell with full Linux capabilities.

I have a lot of luck and fun with the rootfs from here:

> http://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/linux/arm/fedora/rootfs/

You should be able get the Ubuntu for ARM release from somewhere on the net as well.

Comment: Actually, that's what I just did. I've got a debian system running inside Android now. I successfully set the new mac address, but it doesn't seem to change anything. 

I feel like it may not be sending out the new mac address to the hotspot, even though it shows it when I run ifconfig tiwlan0. Would I have to change it permenantly as suggested by many tutorials online by putting a few lines in the /etc/network/interfaces? If I did that within the debian, environment though, it wouldn't carry over to the normal android use, since Android doesn't have an interfaces file in etc.

Answer (score 4):

What I found to work was in stock Android (no root either) get the Android Terminal Emulator from the Market. Type in `ip link show` to find your WLAN card; mine was `eth0` so I will use that as an example. Enter the following:

```
ip link set eth0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ip link set eth0 broadcast XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

To confirm that it switched, type in:

```
ip link show eth0
```

and it should show the new mac address. I haven't tested if it works on a MAC-filtered router, but I think it should work.

Comment: That's basically what I had tried. It showed the correct address, but it strangely wouldn't connect.

Comment: Don't set `broadcast` to anything else than `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`, otherwise stuff breaks - including ARP for a start.

Comment: the mac resets after restarting the wifi. any ideas how to persist the changes?

Comment: Giving me `request send failed:permission denied.` error on Google Pixel with Pie.

Answer (score -1):

only the letters A-F and numbers 0-9 are allowed in a MAC address.

> What is the format of a valid MAC
>   address ?
>
> A normal MAC address looks like this:
>   00:09:5B:EC:EE:F2. It is composed of
>   six octets. The first half (00:09:5B)
>   of each MAC address is known as the
>   Organizationally Unique Identifier
>   (OUI). Simply put, it is the card
>   manufacturer. The second half
>   (EC:EE:F2) is known as the extension
>   identifier and is unique to each
>   network card within the specific OUI.
>   Many access points will ignore MAC
>   addresses with invalid OUIs. So make
>   sure you use a valid OUI code when you
>   make up MAC addresses. Otherwise, your
>   packets may be ignored by the Access
>   Point. The current list of OUIs may be
>   found here.
>
> Make sure that that the last bit of
>   first octet is 0. This corresponds to
>   unicast addresses. If it is set to 1,
>   this indicates a group address, which
>   is normally exclusively used by
>   multicast traffic. MAC addresses with
>   a source set to multicast are invalid
>   and will be dropped.
>
> - Examples of valid OUIs: 00:1B:23, 08:14:43, AA:00:04 because 0, 8 and A
>     are even
> - Examples of invalid OUIs: 01:1B:23, 03:23:32
>
> In particular, it is recommended that
>   the first octet is 00.

Comment: Yeah, the xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx was just an example. I'm definitely using a correct mac address.